# How to prevent Firefox from updating to version 57 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

FF 57 will break legacy extensions.  I have several of these which I want to keep working.  For this, I want to prevent FF from auto-updating. However, although previously you had the option of doing that in the "Advanced" tab of the settings panel (as can be seen below)...

[image]

...now in FF 56, that option has been silently removed.  The advanced tab doesn't even exist any longer:

[image]

This is very annoying and has put us users in collision course towards the day FF 57 is imposed on us, and we suddenly find ourselves with missing functionality on which we have come to rely.

But there may be some other way I'm not aware of to prevent auto-updating.  I know that updating brings security fixes, new features, etc.  I'm not interested in any of those.  I just want my normal work not to be disrupted by missing extensions.

Can forced auto-updating be prevented in any other way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply do:

```
sudo apt-mark hold firefox
```

This will add firefox package to the list of packages who should not recieve updates.

To reverse it:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold firefox
```

You can list the packages on hold via:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

For further information see [`man apt-mark.8`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-mark.8.html)

Comment: This seems to be the answer.  I hope FF doesn't have a way to just update itself without apt.

Comment: It doesn't have a self updating way yet, when you put the package on hold you wont get updates via `apt dist-upgrade`. but if you ever unhold the package you will get updated with the rest of the system and then you would have to use .deb files for install to revert back.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've installed firefox via apt, so:

```
echo firefox hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```